# Asymptotic behaviour of $\varphi''(x)=F(\varphi(x))$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics

I'm concerned with the discussion of a ODE, especially the discussion of the solution.
I've got the assumptions that there is the relation $\varphi''(x)=F(\varphi(x))$ for all $x$ on $\mathbb{R}$. Forthermore I know (by the notation $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty} \varphi(x)=:\varphi_0$) that $F(\varphi_0)=0$ and $F'(\varphi_0)>0$.
The statement now is: $\varphi(x)\rightarrow\varphi_0$ exponentially as $x\rightarrow\infty$ (and therefore $F'(\varphi(x))\rightarrow F'(\varphi_0)$ exponentially as well).

But I don't know how to check that statement. Maybe someone have got some ideas?

Comment: Probably I should mention, that the functions are assumed to be sufficiently continuous

Comment: I might try something along the lines of this: when $\varphi \approx \varphi_0$ we should have $$F(\varphi) \approx F(\varphi_0) + F'(\varphi_0)(\varphi-\varphi_0) = F'(\varphi_0)(\varphi-\varphi_0),$$ so $$\varphi'' \approx F'(\varphi_0)(\varphi-\varphi_0)$$ and hence $$\varphi \approx Ae^{-x\sqrt{F'(\varphi_0)}} + Be^{x\sqrt{F'(\varphi_0)}} + \varphi_0.$$ Since $\varphi \to \varphi_0$ as $x \to \infty$ we must have $B = 0$.  Seeing the right way to do this rigorously is the tricky part.

Comment: @AntonioVargas Thank you for your hint. Maybe you could give me some more how do you get the last one? Is it only integration, you used?

Comment: My ansatz was different. Multipling the equation with $\varphi'$ gives     $\varphi''(x)\varphi'(x)-F(\varphi(x))\varphi'(x)=0$ and so  $\varphi'(x)(\frac{1}{2}\varphi'(x)-F(\varphi(x)))=0$. But then I've got no idea how to connect that with exponential growing or decaying.